# web2py. no such table error

Tags: python, web2py

I have an error `no such table: mytable`, even though it is defined in `models/tables.py`. I use sqlite. Interesting enough, if I go to `admin panel -> my app -> database administration` then I see a link `mytable`, however when I click on it then I get `no such table: mytable`.
I don't know how to debug such error? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web2py keeps the structure it *thinks* the table has in a separate file. If someone has manually dropped the table, web2py will still think it exists, but of course you get an error when you try to actually *use* the table

Look for the `*.mytable.table` file in the databases directory

Comment: Is there way to tell web2py create the table?

Comment: If I look at `myapp/databases/` then I see file with `numbersletters_mytable.table`, whehere `numbersletters` some sequence of numbers and letters, so it looks like table exist?

Comment: @msh, you should move that file away and restart web2py. web2py will recreate the table from the model